# Proptest: Strategy to generate vectors of vectors

Tags: rust, property-based-testing, proptest

I want to generate DAGs with [*proptest*](https://docs.rs/proptest/0.10.1/proptest/). The algorithm that I pick would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12792416/461597). I've written the plain algorithm below -- but I need help transforming this to a *proptest* [**strategy**](https://altsysrq.github.io/proptest-book/proptest/tutorial/strategy-basics.html).

What would a strategy need to look like that did the same as the below code but without using a random number generator? (It goes without saying that random number generators are bad for property-based testing.)

Standard code without proptest strategy:
(https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2de4a757a96d123bf83b5157e0633d33)

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", random_vec_of_vec());
}

fn random_vec_of_vec() -> Vec<Vec<u16>> {
    const N: u16 = 30;
    const K: usize = 3;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let length: u16 = rng.gen_range(0, N);
    let mut outer = vec![];
    for index in 1..length {
        let mut inner = vec![0u16; rng.gen_range(0, K)];
        for e in &mut inner {
            *e = rng.gen_range(0, index);
        }
        // De-duplicate elements. Particularly a problem with `index < K`.
        inner.sort();
        inner.dedup();
        outer.push(inner);
    }
    outer
}
```

### Previous work

I tried using the [vec](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/collection/fn.vec.html) function, but I would need to nest two `vec` functions. And, the inner vec function could only generate values up to the index in the outer vector.

```rust
use proptest::collection::vec;
// INDEX should be the value of the position of the inner vector
// in the outer vector. How could the be found?
let strategy = vec(vec(1..INDEX, 0..K), 0..N);
```

The [`index`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/sample/struct.Index.html#method.index) method is not helpful because the right size would still not be known.

Comment: What's the question here? Is it [how to use proptest](https://altsysrq.github.io/proptest-book/proptest/index.html)? Or is it something more specific?

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, I am aware of the docs, the book and the [logrocket-post](https://blog.logrocket.com/property-based-testing-in-rust-with-proptest/). Not sure why that comment got deleted — after all it was the other person cussing at me. I’ll answer your question next.

Comment: @Jmb I had no problem getting started with proptest. The problem for this strategy is that three strategies have to be combined at various levels. I will post an answer — since I managed to solve this. The way to do it for me, was to keep the structure of the *rand*-based code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this, is to replace each `rng.gen_range()` call with a strategy. Nested strategies must then be connected with [`prop_flat_map`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/strategy/trait.Strategy.html#method.prop_flat_map).

In the below code, I replaced my pattern
`let length = rng.gen_range(0, N); for i in 1..length { .. }`, with a new function `vec_from_length(length: usize)`, which returns a Strategy.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use proptest::collection::hash_set;
    use proptest::prelude::*;
    use std::collections::HashSet;

    proptest! {
        #[test]
        fn meaningless_test(v in vec_of_vec()) {
            let s = sum(&v);  // sum of the sum of all vectors.
            prop_assert!(s < 15);
        }
    }

    fn vec_of_vec() -> impl Strategy<Value = Vec<Vec<u16>>> {
        const N: u16 = 10;

        let length = 0..N;
        length.prop_flat_map(vec_from_length).prop_map(convert)
    }

    fn vec_from_length(length: u16) -> impl Strategy<Value = Vec<HashSet<u16>>> {
        const K: usize = 5;
        let mut result = vec![];
        for index in 1..length {
            // Using a hash_set instead of vec because the elements should be unique.
            let inner = hash_set(0..index, 0..K);

            result.push(inner);
        }
        result
    }

    /// Convert Vec<HashSet<T>> to Vec<Vec<T>>
    fn convert(input: Vec<HashSet<u16>>) -> Vec<Vec<u16>> {
        let mut output = vec![];
        for inner in input {
            output.push(inner.into_iter().collect())
        }
        output
    }
}
```

One more thing: An `impl Strategy<Value=Vec<T>>` can be generated from either the `vec` function (a strategy of vector) or from a vector of strategies! In the above code, I do this through having `result` be `push`ed with `hash_set(..)` which is a Strategy. The type is thus something like `Vec<Strategy<T>>` not `Strategy<Vec<T>>` (pedantic: Strategy is not a type, maybe).