# How to generate all possible Directed Acyclic Graphs given the Nodes/vertices ( large -- 50) and their degrees/directions

Tags: graph, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, isomorphism

I have a given set of nodes/vertices (finite and may be 50 to 100). Each vertex/node has one or more directions associated with it, as in, a node shall have 1 incoming and 2 outgoing, or 1 incoming and 1 outgoing.

Question 1:
How do I generate all possible DAGs? I actually need planar, non-isomorphic DAGs, Nonetheless, any idea/suggestion to first generate all possible DAGs is much appreciated.

Please note: The nodes have their directions/order pre-defined.

Question 2:
Shall a DAG be represented by its adjacency matrix as NXN digit number?

P.S:

I am new to graph theory. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790337/generating-a-random-dag